# Resolving promises inside factory function

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, firebase, jasmine

Okay, I really really googled a lot to get a grasp on this problem. But every possible solution I found on google or here on StackOverflow does not really tackle my problem.

**My Factory**
I have a function (`find`) in my factory which uses a service to retrieve data from a database (in my case Firebase). After the data has been successfully been fetched, the retrieved data is assigned to a variable.

**The Problem**
When I call `find` in my test suite the variable which contains the retrieved data is still null. So I guess the promise hasn't been resolved. And I have no idea how to achieve that.

**My Code**
*resource/user.js*

```
.factory('User', ['$firebaseRef', function UserFactory($firebaseRef) {

    var ref = $firebaseRef.child('users');

    var User = function(path) {
        this.data = null;
        this.find(path);
    };

    User.prototype.find = function(path) {
        var self = this;

        if (!path) {
            return;
        }

        ref
            .child(path)
            .on('value', function(snapshot) {
                self.data = angular.extend({}, {$id: snapshot.key()}, snapshot.val());
            });
    };

    return User;
}]);
```

*resource/test/user.spec.js*

```
describe('resource.user', function() {
    var User, userRef;

    beforeEach(module('firebase'));

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('resource.user')
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(_User_) {
        User = _User_;
        userRef = new User();

        spyOn(userRef, 'find').and.callThrough();

        userRef.find('some-uuid');
    }));

    it('should resolve the user data when a valid `id` has been given', function() {
        console.log(userRef.data);
        expect(userRef.find).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(userRef.data).not.toBeNull(); // This test fails "Expected null not to be null."
    });

});
```

The examples/tutorials I have found on the internet only deal with "handle service promises **inside controllers**".

Since I am testing the service itself I can't mock the functions (at least thats what I'm thinking).

Can someone put me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Use below approach, `$firebaseObject` works with promise.

resource/user.js

```
.factory('User', ['$firebaseRef','$firebaseObject', function UserFactory($firebaseRef,$firebaseObject) {

    var ref = $firebaseRef.child('users');

    var User = {
        find:function(uid){
            if(!uid)
                return;
            return $firebaseObject(ref.child(uid));
        }
    };

    return User;
}]);
```

resource/test/user.spec.js

```
describe('resource.user', function() {
    var User;

    beforeEach(module('firebase'));

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('resource.user')
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(_User_) {
        User = _User_;
    }));

    it('should resolve the user data when a valid `id` has been given', function() {
        User.find('some-uuid').then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            expect(data).not.toBeNull(); 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That is not a good approach. AngularFire should be used in a scope context to sync your data with your scope. But thanks for your answer!